# How do I get notified when something is added or removed from an observable list in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have an observable list from Polymer and Dart. I want a getter to run when something is added or removed from the list. How do I do that?

My list:

```
final ObservableList masterList = toObservable([]);
```

My getter:

```
List get subList => masterList.where((item) => item.isDone);
```

When I add or remove from `masterList`, I want `subList` to update the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `changes` to listen for any changes to an observable object. You can put this into the `created()` lifecycle callback:

```
class Example extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
  final ObservableList masterList = toObservable([]);
  created() {
    masterList.changes.listen((List<ChangeRecord> changes) {
      notifyProperty(this, const Symbol('subList'));
    }
  }

  List get subList => masterList.where((item) => item.isDone);
}
```

It's important to remember that `changes` is watching for additions and removals from the `masterList`. You probably don't want the typical `bindProperty` pattern because that just watches for changes to the variable itself (if the variable is set to a different object, then bindProperty will run).

Comment: Is there any way to listen for changes on "isDone" in the items in the masterList and to have this evaluate the subList getter?

Comment: @ChristopheHerreman if you ask that as a StackOverflow question, I think I have an answer :)

Comment: @ChristopheHerreman I just asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994372/how-can-i-listen-for-changes-to-properties-on-objects-inside-a-list-with-dart